# Convert I18n Iphone Files to Android

Tags: android, ios, internationalization

I have an iOS App localized (with Localizable.strings files).

I've built now an Android version. I understand the way the i18n is made on android but I would like to avoid redoing the i18n, as almost all the Strings have the same meaning between iOS and Android.

Are there any tools that will do this conversion, or at least speed up the process?

---

**Edit:** 
Ideally I would like to find a method/tool that would do the following

```
Input:
'iOS Localizable.strings files-(en,fr,it,pt,etc)'
'res/values/strings.xml'

Output:
'res/values-en/strings.xml'
'res/values-fr/strings.xml'
'res/values-it/strings.xml'
'res/values-pt/strings.xml'
'res/values-etc/strings.xml'
```

Comment: I've always used Notepad++ with macros finished off with a little search and replace.  Took me about 10 minutes to my last one with about 300 strings in it.  You start recording, edit one line (using CTRL-END, CTRL-RIGHT ARROW etc (assuming Windows)) then run macro multiple times->run to end of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specialised service here: [Loco](http://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android).

There are threads here on SO which deal with conversation:

- [Are there any tools to convert an Iphone localized string file to a string resources file that can be used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141118/are-there-any-tools-to-convert-an-iphone-localized-string-file-to-a-string-resou?rq=1)
- [Any tool to convert Android's XML localization to iPhone's .strings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107299/any-tool-to-convert-androids-xml-localization-to-iphones-strings-file?lq=1)

Another possiblity would be to use an online translation service. These services accepts text not only in Android and iPhone but also in many other formats. Upload the android text and download the iPhone text. A list of available services can be found on SO, see [Any collaborative tool/website to localize an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520891/any-collaborative-tool-website-to-localize-an-android-app) Some of these services are commercial, but even these provide a 30days test period. But note that the main focus is on translation and not on conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that does that: https://github.com/wrapp/LocalizedStrings2Android

Put it in a jar and it is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool I created on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/danielgindi/x9njj9gj/

```
[StackOverflow requires me to write some code here because of the JSFiddle link]
```

Just paste in your localization strings inside the correct box, and you'll get the converted version in the other boxes (Between Android, iOS, and JS).

This tries to preserve comments too.

Cheers!